# Why is it necessary to save all OneToMany objects individually with Hibernate?

Tags: java, hibernate

Consider a class such as the following:

```
class Person {
  @Column(name = "id")
  Integer id;

  @Column(name = "name")
  String name;

  @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, mappedBy = "owner")
  List <Car> cars;
}

class Car {
  @Column(name = "name")
  String name;

  @Column(name = "plate")
  String plate;

  @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
  @JoinColumn(name="id", nullable=false)
  Person owner;
}
```

Now, when we come to save a person object:

```
Transaction tx = session.beginTransaction();   
session.save(person);
for (Car c : person.getCars()) {
  session.save(c);
}
tx.commit();
```

Is it not possible just to hand Hibernate the java object and let it save everything?

Comment: Yes it is. Read about cascading

Answer (score 0):

Thanks aviad.   That's exactly what I needed.
For future reference, here's the code I used...

```
class Person {
  @Column(name = "id")
  Integer id;

  @Column(name = "name")
  String name;

  @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, mappedBy = "owner", orphanRemoval=true)
  @Cascade({CascadeType.SAVE_UPDATE, CascadeType.DELETE})
  List <Car> cars;
}

class Car {
  @Column(name = "name")
  String name;

  @Column(name = "plate")
  String plate;

  @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
  @JoinColumn(name="id", nullable=false)
  Person owner;
}
```

The only real difference is that you have to make sure any updates to the linked objects are done before saving the parent.

i.e.   This will not work.

```
Transaction tx = session.beginTransaction();   
session.save(person);
for (Car c : person.getCars()) {
  c.setName(c.getName() + " Update test");
}
tx.commit();
```

But this will

```
Transaction tx = session.beginTransaction();   
for (Car c : person.getCars()) {
  c.setName(c.getName() + " Update test");
}
session.save(person);
tx.commit();
```

Comment: First save the dependent List of Cars to be mapped to the person and then use the List reference to save the Person !

Comment: It is like - for associating a foreign key in our table, it should already exist in another table as primary key - works this way.